# Can I compare Real48 using generics.defaults?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe8

The following code to compare two Real48's (6-byte float) compiles and runs, but either generates non-nonsensical results or generates a AV.

```
program Project44;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Defaults;

begin
  try
    WriteLn(System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer<Real48>.Default.Compare(100.0,100.0));
    WriteLn('all ok, press space');
  except on E:exception do
    WriteLn(e.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn
end.
```

It should output 0, but if it does not bomb first it outputs `-92` or some other incorrect value.

Is this bug still present in the lastest XE8?
And if so, has it been reported before, I cannot find anything on the https://quality.embarcadero.com, but if there's an older QC I would like to refer to that.

Finally....
How do I compare two `REAL48` types using `TComparer<something>`?

**EDIT :**
this was the fix I settled upon:

```
interface
...snip...
[Test]
procedure TestReal48;
...snip...  
    TTest<T> = record
  private
    class var Def: System.Generics.Defaults.IComparer<T>;
    class var F: FastDefaults.TComparison<T>;
  public
    class function Real48Comparison(const Left, Right: T): Integer; static;

implementation

procedure TestDefault.TestReal48;
var
  OldDef: System.Generics.Defaults.IComparer<Real48>;
begin
  OldDef:= TTest<Real48>.Def;
  TTest<Real48>.Def:= System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer<Real48>.Construct(TTest<Real48>.Real48Comparison);
  TTest<Real48>.Test(100.0,100.0);
  TTest<Real48>.Test(100000.0,-10000.0);
  TTest<Real48>.Test(0.0,-10000.0);
  TTest<Real48>.Test(100000.0,0.0);
  TTest<Real48>.Test(0.0,0.0);
  TTest<Real48>.Def:= OldDef;
end;
```

Comment: Filed bug report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11301

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This defect is present in all versions of the compiler. Since `Real48` was deprecated more than a decade ago I would expect that Embarcadero would not change the behaviour, even if you submitted a bug report. Of course, you should still submit a bug report, but I would not hold your breath when waiting for a fix!

You'll have to construct a comparer rather than relying on the default:

```
var
  Comparer: IComparer<Real48>;

function Real48Comparison(const Left, Right: Real48): Integer;
begin
  if Left < Right then
    Result := -1
  else if Left > Right then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

Comparer := System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer<Real48>.Construct(Real48Comparison);
```

---

Why does the default `Real48` comparer fail so hard. Well, it starts here:

```
class function TComparer<T>.Default: IComparer<T>;
begin
  Result := IComparer<T>(_LookupVtableInfo(giComparer, TypeInfo(T), SizeOf(T)));
end;
```

It transpires that `TypeInfo(Real48)` yields `nil`. There would appear to be no type info available for `Real48`. Probably not a great surprise.

Then we reach here:

```
function _LookupVtableInfo(intf: TDefaultGenericInterface; info: PTypeInfo; size: Integer): Pointer;
var
  pinfo: PVtableInfo;
begin
  if info <> nil then
  begin
    pinfo := @VtableInfo[intf, info^.Kind];
    Result := pinfo^.Data;
    if ifSelector in pinfo^.Flags then
      Result := TTypeInfoSelector(Result)(info, size);
    if ifVariableSize in pinfo^.Flags then
      Result := MakeInstance(Result, size);
  end
  else
  begin
    case intf of
      giComparer: Result := Comparer_Selector_Binary(info, size);
      giEqualityComparer: Result := EqualityComparer_Selector_Binary(info, size);
    else
      System.Error(reRangeError);
      Result := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

We take the `else` branch and call `Comparer_Selector_Binary`. So we end up performing a binary comparison. The comparison is actually performed by this function:

```
function Compare_Binary(Inst: PSimpleInstance; const Left, Right): Integer;
begin
  Result := BinaryCompare(@Left, @Right, Inst^.Size);
end;
```

which calls:

```
function BinaryCompare(const Left, Right: Pointer; Size: Integer): Integer;
var
  pl, pr: PByte;
  len: Integer;
begin
  pl := Left;
  pr := Right;
  len := Size;
  while len > 0 do
  begin
    Result := pl^ - pr^;
    if Result <> 0 then
      Exit;
    Dec(len);
    Inc(pl);
    Inc(pr);
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;
```

Not going to be useful for a real valued type.

As for the runtime error that relates to the ABI for `Real48`. It seems that `Real48` parameters are always passed on the stack. That is just not compatible with the use of untyped parameters in `Compare_Binary`.

Comment: Anyway the fix is easy: any var with unknown `typeinfo` 6 bytes in length must be a `Real48`. I wish we could submit patches to the RTL.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer BTW.

Comment: I can explain the runtime error now. Special ABI for `Real48` that is just not compatible with untyped parameters. FWIW your bug report reads more that the issue is the run time error. But I think it's worth stressing that a binary comparison can never be right for a real type.

Comment: Updated the bug report, you're right it's much clearer now. Strangly enough `GetTypeInfo(Real48)` generates tkFloat. So it seems that at some level RTTi for Real48 has been restored. However because the XE7 RTL does not use `GetTypeInfo` (to its own detriment) it does not pick up on the fact that it's a tkFloat and not a tkUnknown.

Comment: That's just the result of the GetType*Kind* function. You cannot do anything with it. And in fact it would require getting the typedata to get the TFloatType and then aww, no FloatType for Real48.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, Sorry yes typo, `GetTypeKind`, however SizeOf(T) will tell you it's a Real48 without doubt. _(I can see how that would be a lot of special casing though)._